# Count ID's by using field values in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a table such that

```
Id  Brand1  Brand2  Brand3  Brand4
0     1       0       0       1
1     1       0       1       0
2     1       0       1       0
3     1       1       0       0
4     1       1       0       1
```

and I am trying to create a table for the number of Ids using brand in combinations.

```
         Brand1  Brand2  Brand3  Brand4
  Brand1      -       2       2       2
  Brand2      2       -       0       1
  Brand3      2       0       -       0
  Brand4      2       1       0       -
```

since they have the same values this would work, too.

```
         Brand1  Brand2  Brand3  Brand4
  Brand1      -       2       2       2
  Brand2      -       -       0       1
  Brand3      -       -       -       0
  Brand4      -       -       -       -
```

Comment: Hi, what exactly did you try ? Do you have any code to provide ? 
Please check [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: the logic is not clear at all. I mean what are you counting or adding up?

Comment: The below table is the number of IDs having "1" for both brands. such as for Brand1 and Brand2, there are two IDs who has value of 1 (ID=[3, 4])

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that with a simple matrix product:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Brand1': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    'Brand2': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
    'Brand3': [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    'Brand4': [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
})
cross = df.T @ df
print(cross)
#         Brand1  Brand2  Brand3  Brand4
# Brand1       5       2       2       2
# Brand2       2       2       0       1
# Brand3       2       0       2       0
# Brand4       2       1       0       2
```